Python multiprocessing: multiprocessing.Value reverting to default value after process is started
I have a multiprocessing.Process class that I made to emulate a real device, like this:
class EmulatorViron(multiprocessing.Process):
    BIND_PORT_RANGE = [30800, 30900]
    socket = None
    bind_port: int
    client = None
    DEFAULT_PASSWORD = ""

    COOLING_TEMP_MIN = 15.0
    COOLING_TEMP_MAX = 90.0

    HEATING_COEF = 2.5  # roughly degrees / sec
    COOLING_COEF = 2.0  # roughly degrees / sec

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        logger.info(f"Received kwargs: {kwargs}")
        # update the DEFAULT_SETTINGS with the init arguments
        self.bind_port = int(kwargs["bind_port"]) if "bind_port" in kwargs else None  # used in ETH emulator
        self.socket = None
        # Initialize version
        self.device_identifier = kwargs.get("device_identifier", "VIRON")
        self.laser_password = multiprocessing.Value(
            c_wchar_p, kwargs.get("laser_password", self.DEFAULT_PASSWORD)  # Default password is always valid!
        )
        logger.info(f"Current password: {self.laser_password.value}")
        self.operation_delay = kwargs.get("operation_delay", 1)
        self.delay_between_commands = kwargs.get("delay_between_commands", 0.1)

        # initialize rest of the state
        self.user_authenticated = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("user_authenticated", False))
        self.fire_mode = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("fire_mode", False))
        self.standby_mode = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("standby_mode", False))
        self.is_flashing = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("is_flashing", False))
        self.is_switching = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("is_switching", False))
        self.user_shots = multiprocessing.Value("i", kwargs.get("user_shots", 8001))
        self.fl_mode_int = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("fl_mode", True))  # True: Internal, False: External
        self.qs_mode_int = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("qs_mode", True))  # True: Internal, False: External
        self.qs_delay = multiprocessing.Value("i", kwargs.get("qs_delay", 50))
        self.cooling_temp = multiprocessing.Value("f", kwargs.get("t_cool", self.COOLING_TEMP_MIN))

        # Inititalize status flag
        self.bnc_interlock = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool, kwargs.get("bnc_interlock", False))  # generic for all lasers

        # Initialize port
        self.client_port_name = ""
        self._initialize_connection()
        self._running_flag = multiprocessing.Event()

I'm trying to set the password to "helloworld" via the kwargs, and it works, but when I actually start the process, it seems to be reinitialized, and it goes back to an empty string.
I've noticed it does the same for other variables, like the bind_port, which is not a multiprocessing.Value, so it's not a problem with just the multiprocessing values. The only thing I haven't tested explicitly is if there isn't some race condition between when I create this object and when I call the start function, but I can't imagine that's the case. Effectively, I discovered that the variables held by the object in the parent process don't pass over to its counterpart in the child process, unless I missed something else that's very obvious, but I can;t find anything else about this online.

i guess the problem is that somewhere in the code, a EmulatorViron object is created without kwargs. in this case it would take all the default values from the class. try to remove **kwargs with args without default values. this will crash exactly at the point where EmulatorViron is created to locate the problem. but i am only guessing!

Yeah, I just realized there is another function where this starts programmatically without the same kwargs, and it's the one where I've been trying to connect to. I've provided the same kwargs to that instance as well and now everything works swimmingly. Thanks for the pointer!
